# Filtering children in a composite component

Tags: jsf-2.2, composite-component

When writing a composite component, is there a way to insert only a certain subset of the component's children?
`<cc:insertChildren/>` inserts all children - but what if I only wanted to insert, say, children that are `<myns:specialCompositeSubTag .../>` tags at a specific point and all others at some other point? Something like:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputLabel value="My special composite sub tags:" />
    <composite:insertChildren condition="#{type == myns:specialCompositeSubTag}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="All other child tags:" />
    <composite:insertChildren condition="#{type != myns:specialCompositeSubTag}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

Is that possible? If not, what would be an alternative solution?